# Getting an error when trying to access the pixel values of a BGRA image opencv/c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I am getting this error:

Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0]) in cv::Mat::at

Problem Statement: I am trying to read each pixel value of the image.

```
int main()
{
   std::string path = "E://Trial//lambo.png";
   cv::Mat src = cv::imread(path);
   cv::Mat srcBgra;
   cv::cvtColor(src, srcBgra,cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);

   std::cout<<"---Channels:"<<srcBgra.channels()<<std::endl;

   for(int i=0; i<srcBgra.rows; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j< srcBgra.cols; j++)
      {
         cv::Vec4b pixelValue = srcBgra.at<cv::Vec4b>(j,i);
         std::cout<<"Pixel: "<<pixelValue<<std::endl;
      }
      
   }  
   cv::imshow("Display", src);
   cv::imshow("Display 2", srcBgra);
   cv::waitKey(0);
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting abort error. Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0]) in cv::Mat::at

Any suggestions?

Please note: If I remove the Mat::at function part, the program is working fine. imshow() function is displaying both the images.

Comment: `E://Trial//lambo.png` looks very strange, did you actually mean to write `E:\\Trial\\lambo.png` instead?

Comment: srcBgra.at<cv::Vec4b>(i, j);